# Is there an event to capture the Submit button's press event in a Google form/survey?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a Google form with some fields like Email Address, Name, etc.   What I'd like to have happen is this:

1. User presses "Submit" after they've filled in the fields.
2. I look at what is in the Email Address field to check if it exists in a column from a spreadsheet.
3. If the Email Address doesn't exist, I append it to that column to maintain a list of unique (by email) registrants.

Figured that it would mean overriding a Submit-related event, adding in my logic for checking some cells, and then writing to the (last cell + 1), but I can't seem to find anything for the event of that button.  Instead, **all the submission event questions/search results I've seen are about making a new form and submit button from scratch**.  To reiterate: I can't find anything about the *default* Google form/survey's Submit button and hope to avoid manually adding a submit button since that default one is already provided.

Is there a way to detect that default Submit button's press for a default Google form/survey?  If so, what's the name of that event and can I override it?

Comment: Maybe you can use a normal button instead and write your own validation including the validation of the email address in the spreadsheet. Check out the example of [Waqar Ahmad](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/applications/contactus-form). If you need an example to check if the email already exists let me know I'll place the code I use.

Comment: That example also adds the submit button manually at the following lines. 
-------
    var submitButton = app.createButton("Submit").setHeight("20px")
      .setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "12px");
...
    buttonGrid.setWidget(0, 0, submitButton)
------- 
That would mean a separate Submit button than the one that is included automatically in a Google form/survey.  Does this mean that I must resort to a manually-created submit button in order to detect when the submit button is pressed, or is there an event for the *default* submit button in Google forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the onSubmit trigger https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events

Comment: Strange, I don't see any "onSubmit" described on that page and using my browser's Find functionality yields 0 matches for the text "onSubmit".  The example shown on that page adds a new submit button, which means something separate from the default Google form's Submit button.  Does that mean that there is indeed no way to capture the event of the *default* submit button on a Google form/survey?

Comment: ? are you talking about the same page ? *Spreadsheet Form Submit Events* is definitely on the page @Edo is referencing...

Comment: I see.  The onSubmit is to be inferred from the example about onEdit.  Thanks for pointing out my overlooking, @Sergeinsas.